# Count number of row that contain two exact strings

Tags: python, pandas

This is my df1

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        ["apple,orange,milk"],
        ["orange,watermelon,apple"],
        ["milk,banana,apple"]
    ], 
    columns=['fruits']
)

df1

0 apple,orange,milk
1 orange,watermelon,apple
2 milk,banana,apple
```

This is my df2

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(["apple","orange","banana"], columns=['fruits'])

df2

0 apple
1 orange
2 banana
```

I want to find number of row that the two exact strings occur together. For example, count number of row when apple and milk occur together in the row 
This is my code

```
for i,row in df2.iterrows():
    for j,rows in df1.iterrows():
        b = (rows.str.contains('(?:\s|\S|[,;])milk(?:\s|\S|[,;])') & rows.str.contains('(?:\s|\S|[,;])+df2.iloc[i]+(?:\s|\S|[,;])')).sum()
        if b>0:
            c=c+1
    print(c)
```

The output I got from here is always 0

```
0
0
0
```

The output supposed to be:

```
2
1
1
```

Comment: why pandas? you need to store results inside? how you select witch words to search?

Comment: Sorry, I'm a beginner to python. I thought df2.iloc[i] can select which word to search, but the result doesn't show like that. This is my problem

Comment: Is output correct according to "find number of row that the two exact strings occur together"? If so, could you provide more explanation about output?

Comment: '2' should be represent there is 2 rows apple and milk occur together...

Comment: Thanks I got this. Then why rest [1,1] rows? Another valid question is: how you select which words to search?

Comment: one row for orange and milk, one row for banana and milk. I thought df2.iloc[i] could select the word by array, which mean when i=0, the word is apple, but end up no, this is my problem

Comment: Your code doesn't work because (1) it doesn't provide a proper input to the DataFrame constructor and (2) `pd.dataframe` doesn't exist, unlike `pd.DataFrame`.

Comment: sorry, i actually mean pd.DataFrame, typo error...

Answer (score 2):

First, your constructor for the DataFrame doesn't work because it's misspelt and because it provides the wrong input. Correcting to:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(["apple,orange,milk", "orange,watermelon,apple", "milk,banana,apple"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(["apple", "orange", "banana"])
```

Second, your question is unclear. If I were to rephrase it, I would say something along the lines of: 'I want to find the count of times that a two search terms appear in the same cell, over a set of search terms'. I'm not 100pc that is more clear, however. That said...

---

Create a function which uses string contains taking two specific parameters (and the necessary items for identifying where it ought to search):

```
def find2(df, col, s1, s2):
    return sum(df[col].str.contains(s1) & df[col].str.contains(s2))
```

What this does is that it asks across the column, whether any row contains search term `s1` or `s2`. Then it intersects the two and sums the number of results. Executing:

```
df2[0].apply(lambda i: find2(df1, 0, 'milk', i))
Out[10]: 
0    2
1    1
2    1
Name: 0, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

First, as posted by @ifly6, your question needs to fix the dataframe creation.

Secondly, I assume (differently from the other answer) that you want to find how many contiguous strings as defined in `df2` appear for each `df1` row. A solution can be to first create the possible contiguous strings from `df2` and then iterate through `df1` to see if there is any match and how many words does the match contains. For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import itertools

def contiguous_indices(xs):
    n = len(xs)
    indices = list(range(n+1))
    for i,j in itertools.combinations(indices,2):
        yield xs[i:j]

df1=pd.DataFrame(["apple,orange,milk","orange,watermelon,apple","milk,banana,apple"])
df2=pd.DataFrame(["apple","orange","banana"])

# Define the list of possible contiguous strings in df2
s_list = []
for indx_list in contiguous_indices(range(df2[0].size)):
    s = ''
    for indx in indx_list:
        s += df2[0][indx] + ','
    s_list.append(s[:-1])
print(s_list) 
# ['apple', 'apple,orange', 'apple,orange,banana', 'orange', 'orange,banana', 'banana']

# Iterate through df1 and count max number of contiguous strings matches
for i, s1 in df1.iterrows():
    c_max = 0
    s_save = ''
    for s in s_list:
        if s in s1[0] and len(s.split(',')) > c_max:
            c_max = len(s.split(','))
            s_save = s
    print(i, c_max, s_save)
```

The output will be:

```
0 2 apple,orange
1 1 apple
2 1 apple
```